# Bootstrap won't add second, third background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So im creating a website in bootstrap and im having 3 backgrounds under each other in div's. The thing is, the second and third background won't show up under the first one. So the page just shows up as one div with only the .one background, the other ones won't appear. It worked before... so I don't know if I messed something up that ruined it or something?

HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid one">
    <nav>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">HOME</a>
            <br>
            <a class="nav-link" href="">OVER DE CAMPAGNE</a>
            <br>
            <a class="nav-link" href="">WORD JIJ BESPEELD?</a>
        </li>
    </nav>
    <img class="sire" src="img/Sire.png">
        <h2 class="headline">Wees geen pop,<br>
            want je valt hardop
        </h2>
        <div class="center"><img class="marionet" src="img/marionet.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid two">

</div>

<div class="container-fluid three">

</div>        

</body>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    font-family: Zing Rust Demo Base;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 1.75;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Zing Rust Demo Base;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: white;
}

.headline {
    padding-top: 400px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.sire {
    height: 50px;
    width: 125px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 450px;
}

.marionet {
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: -800px;
    margin-left: 570px;
}

.center {
    display: inline;
}

.one {
    background-image: url(../img/Deel1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.two {
    background-image: url(../img/Deel2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.three {
    background-image: url(../img/Deel3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because those containers are empty. You need to add at least one row-column pair into each one.

Once you have created those row-column pairs you either need to add some content into the columns or you need to specify the height for those columns otherwise they will be zero height and that's the reason why you don't see those background images.

This is what the code for the 2 empty containers should look like:

```html
<div class="container-fluid two">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        Content <br> goes <br> here...
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid three">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            Content goes here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And of course, you can put more than one column into each row.

Comment: Is that clear now? Without any content inside those 2 containers have zero height and that's why you don't see anything.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear, thanks for the help! Didn't know it was that easy